# Should I start a new Django app with version 1.8?

Tags: python, django

I'm about to create a new custom Django app for my organization. (I'm a brand new Django developer; this will be my first one apart from the occasional "Hello world" I've done as a prototype.)

I'm on a shared hosting provider, which indicates that for Django applications, we should use Django version 1.8 (even though 1.10 is the current version) because 1.8 is the last version that supports FastCGI. Am I setting myself up for having a worthless app a few years from now once 1.8 is no longer supported? Would one expect that by the time 1.8 is no longer supported, the shared web hosting world will have moved on to WSGI or some form of workaround? Or is that a fundamental impossibility? Will I find in a couple of years that I've developed an application that is unusable on the host I've produced it for?

Alternatively, should I be considering some other development tool for the situation I'm in? I'm on a shared host, and I'll be doing a fairly vanilla web front end / database back end style setup.

Answer (score 3):

> Am I setting myself up for having a worthless app?

Nope. You will have your project working, and if you ever want to upgrade and find it difficult to jump 3 version at once (1.8 LTS to 1.11 LTS) you can do it step-by-step with neat deprecation warnings. Though general compatibility between versions is usually very good. You will probably also want to have `requirements.txt` to recreate your virtualenv, and then just dropping away the fcgi trash.

> ... the shared web hosting world will have moved on to WSGI ...?

They will have to if they want to earn money. It is also quite easy to configure so there's no other "fundamental impossibility" than laziness.

> Should I start a new Django app with version 1.8?

I cannot decide for you. I would rather consider changing my hosting. On the other hand there's handful of popular extensions that didn't successfully migrate their master to 1.10 yet (e.g. [grappelli](https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-grappelli)), which could also cause delayed migration of your own projects.

> Should I be considering some other development tool?

Too general. Ever seen [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)? It's neat, but Django comes with more features out of the box.

Comment: "you can do it step-by-step with neat deprecation warnings. ": this is how I upgraded from 1.4 to 1.8. Tedious, but relatively straightforward (and safe when done with version control).

Comment: In addition to what Art said, I usually use LTS versions, even for new projects, because Django releases move too fast for me. So I still use 1.8, although I have no such constraints as your provider.